# Uniform Distribution Probability of 3 Movie times

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, density-function

The question is as follows:

> A short film will show three times tomorrow - at $12:00, 13:30$ and $15:00$. If you arrive at the theatre at a random time between $12:30$ and $14:30$, what is the probability that you will have to wait less than 30 minutes for the next show to start?

So far I've managed this:

1. I modeled $t$ in hours thereby making the PDF =
   $f_X(x) = 1/(b-a) = 1/(3-0) = 1/3$
2. I attempted to find the probability of 30 minutes before each show that I had not missed which in this case would be the $13:30$ and $15:00$ shows giving the equation: $Pr( 13:00 < t < 13:30) + Pr(14:30) = (0.5)*(1/3) + 0 = 0.166... = 0.17$

But I don't think this is all to the answer and I can't figure out what else to do.

Comment: How did you get $0.17$ and what is $Pr(14{:}30)$?

Comment: @Christoph Sorry I don't really know how to format definite integrals on this website... I found the definite integral of 1/3 with 1.5 and 1 as the boundaries and $Pr(14:30)$ would be the probability of the time being 14:30 which would just be 0.

Comment: @Christoph edited the post to to add more detail about my working out

Comment: Your PDF looks wrong. The difference between 12:30 and 14:30 are 2 hours. Fix this and it should be fine.

Comment: The correct answer is 0.25.